# Identifying a metal item buried in my backyard

Tags: plumbing, furnace, backyard

[image]I was digging up a bush stump so we can pour a concrete pad for a condensing unit.  As I dug I uncovered the top of a metal object approximately 3-4ft long and 1.5 feet wide.  It's made of some kind of metal (hard to tell with a fair amount of earth still covering it).  It seems flat on the top and no apparent pipes so far.  I was thinking it might be an old buried fuel oil container, but from what I've researched its fairly small for that.  Any ideas?
Additional info: its about 6 inches from my foundation and another 6 from a more recent addition that protrude from the house.
I should also mention there was an oil storage tank in the basement but that was at least 6-10 ft away and has no obvious connection to this area.

Comment: Can you post some photos?

Comment: I'm at work presently, I'll try to get some photos, any initial thoughts though?  The ends are rounded but the sides seem straight.

Comment: Hard to imagine it's anything but a fuel tank.  Maybe a small one was built with the house but abandoned in favor of a larger tank when fuel prices started going up? In any event you ought to treat it like one until you rule that out, i.e. don't go smashing it up, and use extreme caution if you unearth any pipes.

Comment: Septic or fuel (oil or propane) are the most likely options; while it would be dubious in that location under current codes, it presumably predates them. Then again, perhaps it's pirate treasure.

Comment: Aliens! Confirmation if your photos are all overdeveloped!

Comment: We live in town with a sewer, so I doubt septic.  Yes this house was built in 1930 so probably does predate the codes.  Oh I wish it was pirate treasure, something that would give me money instead of costing it.  Dang alien incubation chambers!

Comment: Weapons cache? Plate protecting underground utilities?

Comment: If you knock on it, does it sound hollow? I agree with others that it's probably a fuel tank, but it could also be something water/drainage related like a dry well. It could also be trash. I was really surprised to find a big chunk of metal in my yard once; turns out it was just some old rusty corrugated roofing.

Comment: Left over ammunition shell from civil war?

Comment: Picture and a couple small details added.

Answer (score 2):

I finished digging it up. It was just an oval piece of concrete (about 3 inch deep) that had the edges wrapped with metal.  0_0  so I guess trash is the closest answer.  Wish I knew what it was t here for...it seemed deliberately placed.

Comment: Could have been a cap off of an old well, cistern, etc that was discarded when the vessel or similar was discarded or filled in.